# Different styling within the same innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to generate an `innerHTML` element dynamically as following:

```
cell1.innerHTML = mainText + "<br>" + subText1 + "<br>" + subText2;
```

I want to style variable `mainText` with a certain `font-size`, `color` and `font-weight` while `subText1` and `subText2` having another.

What is a good way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: mount the html you want to make in another class and inject it to the innerHtml

Comment: @janmbaco Hi, how do I assign a class to a variable? Or how do I split the ```cell1``` into two separate classes?

Comment: I don't know how you have the code, but you should generate a function that does whatever you want. Maybe if you give me more information I can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your variables in spans and assign classes/ style attributes to those spans:

```js
cell1.innerHTML ="<span class=\"myClass\">"+ mainText + " </span><br> <span style=\"font-size:2px\">" + subText1 + "</span> <br> <span style=\"color:red\">" + subText2+"</span>"
```